# python gstreamer for windows

Tags: python, audio, gstreamer

I want to use Python bindings for GStreamer on windows. But looking at the INSTALL file, the gstreamer does it in the unix way. (make make install) . I don't want to install cygwin or other windowsunix environments.

Is there a GPL binary distribution of GStreamer available somewhere? (or a script that can just install it using python setup.py install)

thanks

**UPDATE:** I am using Python 2.6 (or higher). The current packages are only available for Python 2.4 or 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

Found this link GStreamer WinBuilds that has a binary available for Python Gestreamer ( Python2.6) http://www.gstreamer-winbuild.ylatuya.es/doku.php?id=download#developers_files

Comment: Thanks! Also, the project that provides the builds has a [Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/) with up-to-date downloads.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, however I am still going to post these resources as they are great for easy install of gstreamer and python with detailed video and text documentation to follow.  There is not much simple step-by-step out there to get up and running, but this did it for me on windows with python, which was the original intent of this question.

Here is the video resource:
[Video Streaming Made Awesome with GStreamer and Python - sunhacks 2020 Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDY8pf-b1nA)

And the text based version that goes with it for links and references
[Sunhacks Gstreamer 2020 Talk](https://gist.github.com/velovix/8cbb9bb7fe86a08fb5aa7909b2950259)