# How can I Iterate through a list of songs and play them one after eachother

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am looking to iterate through a list of songs such as `Songs = ["Song1.mp3", "Song2.mp3", "Song3.mp3"]` and I want to play each song one after each other.

I have tried various methods, the most suggested seemed to use pygame, however, I have not been able to debug the tremendous amount of errors that come with using it. My main source code and attempt at this is as shown below:

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame
from random import choice
import os

pygame.mixer.init()

Songs = os.listdir("Music\\")

def Play():
       Song = choice(Songs)
       pygame.mixer.music.load("Music\\" + Song)
       pygame.mixer.music.play()

while True:
    play()
```

Upon running this I receive error `pygame.error: ModPlug_Load failed`.

I am running this concurrently inside of a slideshow program I have, I want this code to run as background music and I plan on checking for the end of the song in a Function I already have set.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909266/pygame-fails-to-play-some-mp3-files-but-not-others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_busy) to detect if a music stream is actively playing. Play the next song from the list when no stream is active. e.g:

```py
import pygame

play_list = ["song1.mp3", "song2.mp3", "song3.mp3"]
current_list = []

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        if not current_list:
           current_list = play_list[:]
        current_song = current_list.pop(0)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(current_song)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am going to attempt to work off of this as it throws up some errors that I am going to try and handle. Will keep you posted

Comment: @ShamusWood There was a bug in my code `current_list[:]` needs to be `current_list = play_list[:]`. (answer updated)

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom event which will be triggered when the music is done playing using `pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent()`.

Also you need to run the while loop in a child thread if you want to run concurrently with main application.

Below is an example:

```py
import os
import random
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import pygame

pygame.init()
# create a custom event
MUSIC_DONE = pygame.event.custom_type()
# register the event
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MUSIC_DONE)

folder = "Music\\"
Songs = os.listdir(folder)

def next_song():
    try:
        song = random.choice(Songs)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(folder, song))
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        # update song name
        song_var.set(song)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def pygame_loop():
    next_song()
    while pygame.get_init():
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MUSIC_DONE:
                # current song done playing, play next song
                next_song()

root = tk.Tk()

# label to show the current song being played
song_var = tk.StringVar()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=song_var).pack()

# start the pygame loop in a child thread
threading.Thread(target=pygame_loop).start()

root.mainloop()
# quit pygame
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I still receive the same error `pygame.error: ModPlug_Load failed` upon execution of this code. I am going to redownload the MP3 files as It seems there may be some problems with the way pygame is reading the files.

Comment: I have tested several MP3 files and cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a desktop app, you have multiple options to play a file, usually, it depends:

[image]

Also to avoid Tkinter being stuck, you need to use threads or multiprocess. I recommend you soundfile player, you will find examples here https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/